# How to fetch the value of a session storage in this case

Tags: jquery

I am storing JSON key value pair under `sessionStorage` this way:

```
var currentQuantity = 1;
var vendor_item_id = 20;
var datainsession = {
    itemquant: currentQuantity
};

window.sessionStorage.setItem(vendor_item_id + '', JSON.stringify(datainsession));

for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
    var propertyName = sessionStorage.key(i);
    var propertyvalue = sessionStorage.getItem(propertyName);
    console.log(propertyName + '\t' + propertyvalue);
}
```

While retrieving the key value i am getting it as

```
20  {"itemquant":1}
```

How can I fetch the value as `1`?  This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a7okbf39/

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the `itemquant` property you first need to parse the JSON stored in `propertyvalue` to an object. From there, you can just access the property. Try this:

```
console.log(propertyName + '\t' + JSON.parse(propertyvalue).itemquant);
```

[**Updated example**](https://jsfiddle.net/a7okbf39/1/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the changes to your fiddle. Check and see if this meets ur purpose

https://jsfiddle.net/a7okbf39/3/

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem(vendor_item_id + '', JSON.stringify(datainsession['itemquant']));
```

that's the change